# How do you get the rational submodule of a $C^*$-module (equivalent to a $C$-comodule)?

Tags: coalgebras, comodules

Let $C$ be a coalgebra over a field $K$. Let $M$ be a $C^*$-module. I am trying to understand the rational submodule of $M$, which will carry the structure of a $C$-comodule.

It seems to me that the following sequence of steps can construct the rational submodule of $M$

(1) Let $\{C^\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ be the collection of finite dimensional subcoalgebras of $C$

(2) For each $\alpha\in A$, set

$$I^\alpha:=\{\mbox{$f\in C^*$ $\vert$ $f(C^\alpha)=0$ }\} $$

(3) For each $\alpha\in A$, set

$$ M^\alpha:=\{\mbox{$m\in M$ $\vert$ $xm=0$ for all $x\in I^\alpha$}\}$$

(4) Then $\{M_\alpha\}_{\alpha\in A}$ forms a direct system of submodules of $M$ (?)

(5) Put

$$N=\underset{\alpha\in A}{\varinjlim}\textrm{ }M^\alpha \subseteq M $$

Is it correct that $N$ is the rational submodule of $M$, thus carrying the structure of a $C$-comodule? Is there a reference for this?

If not true in general, is it true under some condition on $C$?